# Angularjs: preview sanitized html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Please find the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/QwG0ky06dpuG6RvfAHmP?p=preview)

I want to display some html preview. The html is already sanitized at the server (for eg: `"&lt;b&gt;HELLO&lt;/b&gt;"`). How can I display the html form. In the example, I want to display `myHtml2` as displayed for `myHtml` (first preview).

### html

```
 <div ng-controller="myController">
      <div ng-bind-html="myHtml"></div>
      <div ng-bind-html="myHtml2"></div>
      <div >{{myHtml2}}</div>
    </div>
```

### js

```
myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$sce', function myController($scope, $sce){
  $scope.myHtml = "<b>HELLO</b>";
  $scope.myHtml2 = "&lt;b&gt;HELLO&lt;/b&gt;";      
}]);
```

### out

```
HELLO
<b>HELLO</b>
&lt;b&gt;HELLO&lt;/b&gt;
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use [`$sce.trustAsHtml`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$sce#methods_trustashtml) and `unsanitize` HTML on your client: http://plnkr.co/edit/h2loxWsPJOELhNvkfHmK?p=preview

```
// From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912501/unescape-html-entities-in-javascript
function htmlDecode(input){
  var e = document.createElement('div');
  e.innerHTML = input;
  return e.childNodes.length === 0 ? "" : e.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}

myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$sce', function myController($scope, $sce){
  $scope.myHtml = "<b>HELLO</b>";
  $scope.myHtml2 = $sce.trustAsHtml(htmlDecode("&lt;b&gt;HELLO&lt;/b&gt;"));

}]);
```

`htmlDecode` from: [Unescape HTML entities in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912501/unescape-html-entities-in-javascript)

However, I would not recommend taking this approach. It feels very hackish and I suspect could lead to vulnerabilities on your site.

Comment: thanks for showing this approach. So, what would you recommend? keep the html unescaped at the server, and only sanitize through Angular at client side? I am curious site like SO, how do they handle this situation. Do they just store markdown, and convert at the client?

Comment: @bsr SO uses [wmd](https://code.google.com/p/wmd/) and renders the Markdown purely on the client side. I would keep the HTML on the client side (or provide `partials` from separate paths from the server) and fetch data using separate API and interpolate the data in using Angular bindings.

Comment: just read http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/06/safe-html-and-xss/ , but not sure what was the final solution as the linked site is down, and it is a post from 08