# angularjs ng-bind-html with html character entities

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind-html, ngsanitize

```
var text1 = "<b>sometext</b>";     
var text2 = "&lt;b&gt;sometext&lt;/b&gt;";
```

`ng-bind-html="text1"` works fine. The result is **sometext**
but `ng-bind-html="text2"` doesn't work. The result is <b>sometext<b>

How can I make`ng-bind-html="text2"` work.
Thank you.

Comment: @simoco why did you edit this? I wanted to show first result is bolded text in html and second result is <b>sometext</b> in html

Comment: So you want in both cases bolded text?

Comment: I edited again :) Thank you anyway.

Comment: @dfsq Yes. especially for the second one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angularjs: preview sanitized html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20572947/angularjs-preview-sanitized-html)

Comment: Actually the result of text2 does work. It just works differently from text1. The result is expected behavior