# Insert HTML (user-defined directives) into view - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

This is my first question on Stackoverflow so please excuse any mistakes I make.
I'm trying to display in the view, some HTML from a template, which I use in the following directive:

```
app.directive('picturegallery', function () {
return {
    scope: true,
    restrict: "E",
    templateUrl: '../../Controllers/pictureGallery.html'
}
```

});

I do this on click by applying `.push`, so `<picturegallery></picturegallery>` gets added to the `$scope.sections`:

```
app.directive("picgallery", function ($compile) {
return function (scope, element, attrs) {
    element.bind("click", function () {
        scope.count++;
        scope.sections.push({ desc: "<picturegallery></picturegallery>" });
        angular.element(document.getElementById('template-id')).append($compile("<picturegallery></picturegallery>")(scope));

    });
};
```

});

I use `$sce.parseAsHtml` as shown below and it works, but the HTML still doesn't get translated to the actual HTML pointed by the template, and simply shows up as `<picturegallery></picturegallery>`. I would like the actual template pointed to by `pictureGallery.html` to show up.

```
$scope.sections = [
        { desc: '<div>hello</div>' },
        { desc: '$sce.parseAsHtml("<picturegallery></picturegallery>")' }

    ];
```

Is there any way I could show up the actual content from the template?
I've already been through a couple of solutions like [Angularjs: preview sanitized html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20572947/angularjs-preview-sanitized-html) on Stackoverflow which suggested the use of `$sce.parseAsHtml` and `$sce.trustAsHtml` but they don't work for my code.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for me with a similar problem was to create a custom filter which allows me to render imported HTML.

```
app.filter('unsafe', ['$sce', function($sce) { return $sce.trustAsHtml; }])
```

In my views I can then display the HTML with the filter:

```
<div>{{myCtrl.someHTML | unsafe}}</div>
```

If this doesn't work out of the box, you'll also need to set a resource white list in your angular config like this:

```
$sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist(['self', 'https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/**']);
```

(The google link is only to demonstrate that you can import external HTML from another website/service and render it as a trusted source)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render the HTML from the template just call the directive in the HTML:

```
<picturegallery></picturegallery>
```

This will load the directive which will in turn load the template.